# QT/QML How to create a frameless window with aero (blurred) background

Tags: qt, window, qml, aero-glass

Following code create a window in QML with Aero background (transparent and blurred).

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtWinExtras 1.0 as Win

Window{
    width: 500
    height: 300
    visible: true
    x: 500
    y: 100

    Win.DwmFeatures {
        topGlassMargin: -1
        leftGlassMargin: -1
        rightGlassMargin: -1
        bottomGlassMargin: -1
    }
}
```

When i add the following line to remove borders and title bar, the blur aspect also go off.

```
flags: Qt.Window|Qt.FramelessWindowHint
```

How to maintain the glass blur effect when no border is visible?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the title bar and the buttons using [`Qt.CustomizeWindowHint`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qt.html#WindowType-enum):

```
Window {
    ...

    Component.onCompleted: {
        flags = (flags | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint) & ~Qt.WindowTitleHint
    }
}
```